# accessing req.body values in express without body-parser

Tags: node.js, express, google-oauth

I'm trying to setup a simple google sign in service with my app.

I recreated a simplified version of the login scheme.

When using `console.log()` on the `id_token` returned by google I get the token as excepted. Within the login file I'm using `xhr.send(JSON.stringify({ token: id_token }));` to send the token back to the backend.

the express app looks something like this:

```
console.clear()
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}))

app.post('/login', (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body)
    console.log(req.body.token)
})

app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

why does `console.log(req.body)` return a correct json object while `console.log(req.body.token)` return undefinied? so far I unfortunately only found ways while using bodyParser.

response with `req.body`:

```
{ '{"token":"eyJ...c9g"}': ''}
```

Edit:

as Mohamed suggested (marked answer) I ended up editing the body itself:

`xhr.send('idtoken=' + id_token);` allowed me to use `console.log(req.body.idtoken)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

body-parser is the same as express.json as you can see here https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js

your req.body has a nested object as a key with a value of an empty string inside the
JSON object itself

```
{ '{"token":"eyJ...c9g"}': ''}
```

this part is a key and its value is an empty string

```
'{"token":"eyJ...c9g"}'
```

try something like `JSON.parse(Object.keys(req.body)[0]).token`

but even if this works it's still not the best practice and you should edit the way your body is sent

Comment: thank you for your answer and explanation. this helped a lot